# Display image with " " character in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, url, iis

I have a problem in my MVC 3 Application
i can't access to my image with url like that:
    http://virtualDirectoryImage.fr/ImageNameContains+.jpg
    or
    http://virtualDirectoryImage.fr/ImageNameContains%2b.jpg

I got Error 404 file not found (the file exist, i can access to others images witch dont contains plus (+) symbol).

How can i do plz?
IIS7 issue? Application issue?

PS: the images are not hosted in my application. (Virtual Directory, on the same Server)

thx for your help

Comment: Did you try `%20` for the whitespace character ?

Comment: I havent problem with white space, just with "+" symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you follow the steps given in the following url

http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/CannotOpenAFileHavingSpecialCharactersInTheFilenameOnIIS.html

basically IIS will block the file names if it contains any special characters.Esspecially if it contains & in the file name for security reasons.It's a good practice to replace the special characters with "_" while uploading the file to the server